# How to invoke request using HTTP 1.1 with conditional GET request

Tags: http, get, request, conditional-statements

I have found [a website](https://varvy.com/tools/if-modified/), where I can check if the certain page supports if-modified-since http header.

I would like to ask how can I invoke the request (using HTTP 1.1) to this website, where:

1. I will ask this document unconditionally
2. another request should contain a conditional request “if modified since” having some recent date (i.e. -5 min)

How should I do this with Fiddler2?

I should obtain the response code "Not modified" in 2nd invoke.

How should I invoke these request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find your solution and what language are you wanting to make the request in